# logout not working in IPAD

Tags: django, authentication

Really weird think happening with my site!

I have a "welcome {{user.email}}" in the top of my base.html page! So far was working fine, but when I tested the site in a IPAD2 and Iphone4, I saw that, the login part wasnt working right!What I mean by that is, if I am logged in the welcome message has been showing, but if I logout, some pages are still showing the welcome message in the top, but if I reload the page then it works fine afterwards!  It seems that JUST ipad is holding some kind of cache! is it that even possible?

Just for record I am not using cache in my django app! my settings.py file has:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

So, I know that django is not messing things up! it is something with ipad!(client side)

does someone have a clue about it?!

**EDIT**

I tried already adding;

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

no success so far though.

**EDIT2**:
This is happening in Safari also! but just in Safari and MAC os!! using Safari in windows works fine!

Answer (score 0):

you're probably holding it wrong...

if you really think it's client side maybe you can try to add some meta tags for cache control and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but check my edit in the post! no working still!